# Java program that tells what coins to give out for any amount of change from 1 cent to 99 cents

Tags: java, methods

I have to  write a Java program that tells what coins to give out for any amount of change from 1 cent to 99 cents. For example, if the amount is 86 cents, the output would be something like the following:

> 86 cents can be given as 3 quarters, 1 dime and 1 penny.

Use coin denominations of 25, 10, 5, and 1. Your program will use the following method(among others):

```
public static int computeCoin(int coinValue,);
// Precondition: 0 < coinValue < 100; 
// Postcondition: returned value has been set equal to the maximum 
//number of coins of the denomination coinValue cents that can be 
//obtained from amount (a different variable) cents. amount has been 
//decreased by the value of the coins, that is, decreased by     
//returnedValue*coinValue.
```

So far this is what I have but I think I am missing more can somebody give me a hand?
And I am also not suppose to use doubles instead int.

```
public class Assignment6{
   public static void main(String [] args){
   amount = (int)(Double.parseDouble(args[0])*100);

   System.out.println("Five: " + computeCoin(500));
   System.out.println("one: " + computeCoin(100) );
   System.out.println("Q : " + computeCoin(25) );
   System.out.println("D : " + computeCoin(10) );
   System.out.println("N : " + computeCoin(5) );
   System.out.println("P : " + computeCoin(1) );
}
```

Comment: You'll need to make `amount` a global variable.

Comment: as far as I can see you are never using the value you store inside amount. and can you please provide computeCoing function or atleast tell what it does?

Comment: @A.R.S.: That's nonsense, global variables are usually neither needed nor a good way to do something. In this particular case, we definitely don't need one.

Comment: so then what is the right procedure

Comment: @NiklasB.: Maybe you're thinking of some other way to do it, but what I was thinking can be seen in my answer below.

Comment: What you _really_ need to do it take a pencil and a piece of paper and work through several sample problems. Performing the algorithm by hand will make it much easier to translate into code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Assignment6 {
    private static int amount = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        amount = (int)(Double.parseDouble(args[0])*100);
        System.out.println("Five: " + computeCoin(500));
        System.out.println("one: " + computeCoin(100) );
        System.out.println("Q : " + computeCoin(25) );
        System.out.println("D : " + computeCoin(10) );
        System.out.println("N : " + computeCoin(5) );
        System.out.println("P : " + computeCoin(1) );
    }

    public static int computeCoin(int cointValue) {
        int val = amount / cointValue;
        amount -= val * cointValue;
        return val;
    }
}
```

The trick here lies in the `computeCoin` method, and in the fact that the division is *integer division*, so `val` will hold the 'maximum' number of coins of the given value (`coinValue`) whose total value does not exceed `amount`.

Comment: Generally, for homework it is considered bad form to give the complete solution.

Comment: Are these down votes really just for giving the full solution?

Comment: thank you all for ur time and help im sorry for the down point @A.R.S.i wish i could do something about it

Comment: Ah it's no problem I'm not in it for the votes, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
public class Assignment6 {
    public static int amount;
    public static int amountPreserv;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        amount = (int) (Double.parseDouble(args[0]) * 100);
                amountPreserv = amount;

        System.out.println("Five: " + computeCoin(500));
        System.out.println("one: " + computeCoin(100));
        System.out.println("Q : " + computeCoin(25));
        System.out.println("D : " + computeCoin(10));
        System.out.println("N : " + computeCoin(5));
        System.out.println("P : " + computeCoin(1));
        System.out.println("Value inputed : " + amountPreserv);
    }

    private static int computeCoin(int i) {
        int cont = 0;
        while (amount > i) {
            amount -= i;
            cont++;
        }
        return cont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, for homework it is considered bad form to give the complete solution.

Comment: is true. especially when dealing with simple problems. I will pay more attention. thanks @JohnB

Comment: the program compiles and everything but if i give it a values the what i get as an out put is this                                         Five: 0
one: 0
Q : 0
D : 0
N : 0
P : 0

Comment: @pasito15 how to you're call the program?

Comment: What you're doing in that `while` loop is just integer division.

Comment: @A.R.S. it's true i see it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest point to make is that making change is a Greedy Algorithm, meaning that the option that moves you closest to the goal at any given time is the most efficient choice. Therefore, for any amount and any denomination, the most efficient algorithm should be something like this:

```
int total;
int[] denom = { w, x, y, z };
int[] count = new int[denom.length]
int i = 0;
while (i < denom.length && total > 0) {
  while ( total >= denom[i] )
  {
    total -= denom[i];
    count[i]++;
  }
  i++
}
```

EDIT: Any denominations is a bit ambitions actually. It's only true of you have a minimum denomination that can guarantee that change can be made every time.

Comment: Generally, for homework it is considered bad form to give the complete solution